# Create an API Gateway Model to return HTML using the JSON Schema

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, api-gateway

I have a python function in Lambda, which is now returning text to my API Gateway API.  I am returning a JSON object which looks like

```
userResponse = functon(return HTML)

return {
"isBase64Encoded": False,
"statusCode": 200,
"body": userResponse
}
```

In the API Gateway console, I believe  have to create a response Model, which follows the [JSON schema](http://json-schema.org/).
[Method Response image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejv4N.png)

The examples I have found in SO refer to body mapping templates, which I can't seem to find where to place in my API Gateway.  Those body mapping templates fail the JSON Schema validation.

I am at a loss as to how to create the model so it will return HTML which the user'a browser will recognize as HTML.
[Model definition image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKwS0.png)

The end result is the output of the Lambda function is HTML which should be displayed in the user's browser as HTML.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched over to using Lambda proxy integration which solved the problem.